# What is the purpose of "{}" in "new int[5]{};"?

Tags: c++, c++11, initialization, new-operator, dynamic-memory-allocation

If we write something like:

```
int *arr = new int[5];
```

In this case, the system dynamically allocates space for 5 elements of type `int` and returns a pointer to the first element of the sequence.

But, once I saw the following code:

```
int *arr = new int[5]{};
```

So, What does mean `{}` after `new` operator? What is the purpose of `{}` in this code?

I have initialized array with my own value, like this:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int* a = new int[5]{1};
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        std::cout<< a[i]<<' ';

    delete[] a;
}
```

Output:

```
1 0 0 0 0
```

Only first element print `1`. Why?

Comment: I recommend you take your time to read [this `new` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new). In the table describing the syntax, note the *initializer* part. Then scroll down to the section about [Construction](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new#Construction) to read more about it.

Comment: This syntax has been in use since c++ 11. It allows to initialize an array with values specified inside the curly braces or in this case with zeros.

Comment: Use std::vector!

Comment: Same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/620137/do-the-parentheses-after-the-type-name-make-a-difference-with-new but with C++11 syntax.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
int *arr = new int[5];
```

performs a [default initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization) (which in this case means the elements of `arr` are *uninitialized*), while

```
int *arr = new int[5]{};
```

is a [value initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization) (which in this case means the elements of `arr` are *zero-initialized*). See the corresponding rules in the links. Specifically for the latter case, the array will be zero-initialized.

Anyway, if there is no other good reason, the use of std::vector should be preferred.

Edit: Concerning your second question: This is due to the initialization rules. You would have to write

```
int* a = new int[5]{1, 1, 1, 1, 1 };
```

The already recommended std::vector supports the syntax you desire:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> a(5, 1);
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        std::cout<< a[i]<<' ';
}
```

https://ideone.com/yhgyJg
Note however the use of ()-braces here. As vector has an constructor for std::initializer_list, calling vector{ 5, 1} would impose a certain ambiguity, which is resolved by always preferring the initializer_list constructor for {}-initializations if provided. So using { } would cause to create a vector with 2 elements of values 5 and 1, rather than 5 elements of value 1.

Comment: Can I initialize an array with my own value?

Comment: Yes. Use e.g. list-initialization for individual array values: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization

Edit: For the language lawyers: This is actually aggregate initialization as arrays are aggregates.

Comment: @Jayesh: Yes. Any expression, whether simply numbers, named constants, variables, mathematical expressions or function calls is allowed in that list.

Answer (score 0):

If you can tell the difference between

```
int a[5];
```

and

```
int a[5] = {0};
```

, the latter of which is a common practice to initialize a local array to *all zero*, you can also port the same syntax to `new`.

Aside from the `std::vector` solution, the most straightforward (and common) non-STL solution is iterating through the array for once:

```
for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(a)/sizeof(int); i ++)
    a[i] = 1;
```

---

FYI, using list initializing causes *all* unspecified array elements to be set to zero, e.g.

```
int a[5] = {[1] = 3};
// Now a is {0, 3, 0, 0, 0}
```